# Let $\Phi: V \rightarrow V^{**}$ isomorhpism and $\alpha$ a family of vectors in $V$. Show that $[\alpha]\subset\Phi^{-1}((\alpha^0)^0).$

Tags: linear-algebra

Some clarifications:

$1)$ The function $\Phi: V \rightarrow V^{**}$ is the isomorphism between $V$ and $V^{**}$ defined by: $\Phi(v)(f) = f(v)$ for every $v\in V$, $f\in V^*$.

$2)$ And given a family $\alpha = (v_i)_{i\in I}$ of vectores in $V$, we define the set $\alpha^0$ by:

$\alpha^0= \{f\in V^*: f(v_i) = 0 \mbox{ for every } i\in I\}$

$3)$ $[\alpha]$ is just a notation for the span of $\alpha$.

Ok, now we can formulate the question:

> Given $\alpha = (v_i)_{i\in I}$ in $V$, show that $[\alpha]\subset\Phi^{-1}((\alpha^0)^0).$ If $\mbox{dim}(V)$ is finite, show that the equality holds.

What've done: Using the same definition as given for $\alpha^0$, we can deduce that $(\alpha^0)^0 = \{g\in V^{**}: g(f) = 0 \mbox{ for every } f\in \alpha^0\}$. So $((\alpha^0)^0)$ is a subset of $V^{**}$ and hence by $\Phi$, the set $\Phi^{-1}((\alpha^0)^0)$ is in $V$. But the question is:

How does that relate to the span of $\alpha$? How can i proceed to show the inclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $v\in [\alpha]$, denote by $g:=\Phi(v)\in V^{**}.$ We note that for every $f\in \alpha^0, f(v) = 0$. To see that, we write $v = \sum_{i\in I}x_iv_i$ and by linearity it follows that $f(v) = \sum_{i\in I}x_if(v_i) = 0$, since $f(v_i) = 0 $ by definition.

Hence, for all $f\in \alpha^0$ it follows that $g(f) = \Phi(v)(f) = f(v) = 0.$ This proves that $\Phi(v) = g\in (\alpha^0)^0$. More generally we have shown that $\Phi([\alpha])\subset (\alpha^0)^0$. Now the result follows by injectivity of $\Phi$.